# PHP - Calculate repeating date based on day of week?

Tags: php, date, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to figure out how to repeat certain tasks on specific days at certain intervals based on an existing date.

For example, I have this:

```
Date                              Task 
2011-01-12                   MJK-0083
```

I want to:

1. Determine the day of the week based on the date provided (in this case, Wednesday)
2. Determine which Wednesday of the month it is (in this case, the 2nd Wednesday)
3. Calculate the date of the 2nd Wednesday in June as the next date this task will occur

I've been looking at some examples, but while I can do bits of it, I can't seem to figure out how to do all of it. For example, I'm using this for step 1:

```
date('l', strtotime('2011-01-12'))
```

But I am lost when it comes to steps 2 and 3... Can someone help me out?

Comment: You'll have to be careful - next month there are five Tuesdays, but this month there are only 4.  Certain days late in the month might not repeat every month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find out which Wednesday of the month it is, you can do this using the day of the month

```
(int)(day_of_month / 7) + (day_of_month % 7 == 0 ? 0 : 1)
```

Thus, for 2012-01-12 you'll get:

```
(int)(12 / 7) + (12 % 7 == 0 ? 0 : 1) = 1 + 1 = 2 -> second Wednesday
```